# Laravel 5.7 foreach wont show anything, but variable is set

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-5.7

My foreach wont show me anything, i am not sure i am passing the variable correctly. The select from my controller works, if i use it in tinker it works. But  it wont show in my view. Not an error just nothing.

My Web page:

```
   //shop
    Route::get('/shop', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@shopindex']);
    //shop categorie
    Route::get('/shop/products/{pcategorie}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@shopCat']);
    //shop product detail
    Route::get('/shop/productdetail/{product}', 'ProductsController@productdetail');
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\pCategorie;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function shopindex()
    {

        $productsOTs = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM wiz.productimages WHERE Afkorting = 'PPI' LIMIT 83, 3"));
        $productcats = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT Productserie FROM wiz.products"));

        return view('shop', compact('productsOTs', 'productcats'));
    }

    public function productdetail(Product $Product)
    {   
        return view('Products.productdetail', compact('productsOT'));
    }

    public function shopCat(pCategorie $pCategorie)
    {
        // Combobox items Cats
        $productcats = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT Productserie FROM wiz.products"));

        // Products from category
        $categorieProds = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Productserie = '$pCategorie'"));

        return view('Products.allproducts', compact('productcats', 'categorieProds'));
    }

}
```

And the foreach from my view:

```
   @if (isset($categorieProds))
      @foreach ($categorieProds as $categorieProd)
         <li>test</li>
      @endforeach

   @else
      <h1>Not found</h1>
   @endif
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: What the result of `dd($categorieProds);`?

Comment: It gives me nothing : []. But if i use the code from the controller in tinker it does give me the records i need

Comment: And dd($pCategorie) please.

Comment: pCategorie works:                                                                                 
  pCategorie {#381 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You aren't calling `get()` on the end of your select queries:</strike>

Raw SQL isn't necessary, best to use the proper query builder methods.

Let's clean up those queries:

```
// instead of writing this
$productcats = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT Productserie FROM wiz.products"));

// write this
$productcats = DB::table('products')->distinct()->select('Productserie')->get();


// bad
$categorieProds = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Productserie = '$pCategorie'"));

// good
$categorieProds = DB::table('products')->where('Productserie', $pCategorie)->get();
```

[Would you like to know more?](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)

Comment: There is not so simple. He has full query in DB::raw select. Looks like he made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: No get, no party.

Comment: Ofc, I gave the same answer 5 min before you, but it is not right. `DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Productserie = '$pCategorie'"))` executes without get, because it has full query in select.

Comment: Also, looks like $pCategories is an object, and he needs its property.

Comment: Thanks for the better looking queries. I am new to laravel, so im still learning. The new queries still wont give me anything

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite queries with `->get()` method. And looks like $pCategorie is object, possibly you should use its property, for example $pCategorie->id.

```
public function shopCat(pCategorie $pCategorie)
{
    // Combobox items Cats
    $productcats = DB::table('wiz.products')
        ->select('Productserie')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    // Products from category
    DB::table('products')
        ->where('Productserie', $pCategorie)
        ->get();

    return view('Products.allproducts', compact('productcats', 'categorieProds'));
}
```

Comment: It gives me a error : Call to a member function get() on array